# sizeof for a structure with char c[0]

Tags: c

```
struct xyz {
    int a;
    int b;
    char c[0];
};
struct xyz x1;
printf("Size of structure is %d",sizeof(x1));
```

Output: 8
why isn't the size of structure 9 bytes? Is it because the character array declared is of size 0?

Comment: yes it is because of that

Comment: Here is a similar question. You will likely find the answers relative to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690718/zero-length-arrays

Comment: This isn't valid C, for several reasons.

Comment: @KerrekSB Perhaps not by the standard, but it is a pretty common `gcc` (and maybe others) extension...

Comment: @twalberg: C99 and C11 allow something similar whereby you say `char c[];`...

Comment: @KerrekSB I realize that, but I don't think `gcc` and other compilers have yet (fully) deprecated the zero-length-array extension, and it's still present in a lot of code...

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, it is valid C. In the terms of the C standard, it is code that may be in a *conforming* program but not in a *strictly conforming* program. C is designed to be extended, and programs that use extensions may be conforming programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zero-length arrays are not in the standard C, but they are allowed by many compilers.

The idea is that they must be placed as the very last field in a struct, but they don't occupy any bytes. The struct works as a header for the array that is placed just next to it in memory.

For example:

```
struct Hdr
{
    int a, b, c;
    struct Foo foos[0]
};

struct Hdr *buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct Hdr) + 10*sizeof(Foo));
buffer->a = ...;
buffer->foos[0] = ...;
buffer->foos[9] = ...;
```

The *standard* way to do that is to create an array of size 1 and then substracting that 1 from the length of the array. But even that technique is controversial...

For more details and the similar *flexible array member* see [this document](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html).

Comment: `Hdr` needs to be `struct Hdr`

Comment: No, the **standard** way is to leave the `[]` empty. Both the `[0]` and `[1]` approaches are wrong.

Comment: @R..: That why I said "_standard_" instead of "__standard__" (and the controversial bit). Besides, the `[]` is C99 only...

Comment: It's also C11. The version of the standard that omits `[]` is almost 25 years old, and two major versions behind. Isn't it time to put it to rest? :)

Answer (score 3):

Your array of characters has a length of 0 and hence the size of c is 0 bytes. Therefore when your compiler allocated a block of memory for that structure it only considers both integers and since you are on a 32-bit environment (assuming so from your result) the size of the structure is 8 bytes.

**Remark**: You can still access the field c without any compiler warnings (compiled with gcc) however it will be some garbage value.

Comment: Accessing `x1.c` might seg fault or other UB.

Comment: Depends on the compiler I suppose? I tried with only gcc using C99 flags.

Comment: 32 bit integers doesn't really imply much about the platform.

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

```
int a;//4

int b;//4

char c[0] ; 0
```

So it is 8.

And
 The sizeof  never return 9 in you struct even if you give a size to char c[];

```
int a;//4  byte
int b;//4   byte
char c[1];// one byte but it should alignment with other.
```

just in this way:

```
^^^^
^^^^
^~~~     //for alignment
```

So, sizeof return 12 not 9

Comment: Could you please elaborate you point Lidong? Is it because of compiler optimizations?

Answer (score 0):

An array of length 0 is actually not permitted in standard C, but apparently your compiler supports it as an extension.

It's one way of implementing the so-called "struct hack", explained in question 2.6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Because C implementations typically don't do bounds checking for arrays, a zero-element array (or in a more portable variant, a one-element array) gives you a base address for an array of arbitrary size. You have to allocate, typically using `malloc`, enough memory for the enclosing struct so that there's room for as many array elements as you need:

```
struct xyz *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr + COUNT * sizeof (char));
```

C99 added a new feature, "flexible array members", that does the same thing without specifying a fake array size:

```
 struct xyz {
     int a;
     int b;
     char c[];
 };
```

Comment: To stay compatible with both `[0]` and `[1]`, we could do `malloc(sizeof *ptr - sizeof ptr->c + COUNT * sizeof (char));` or even `malloc(sizeof *ptr - sizeof ptr->c + COUNT * sizeof ptr->c[0]);`